# Let random variable be $X\sim U([-2,2])$, random variable $Y=5X-4$. Calculate $EY$ and $D^{2}Y$

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

Let random variable be $X\sim U([-2,2])$, random variable $Y=5X-4$.

**Calculate $EY$ and $D^{2}Y$**

D-variance

My take:

$EX=-2$

$D^{2}X$= 4

$EY=E(5x-4)=5EX-4=5*(-2)-4=-14$

$D^{2}Y=D^{2}(5X-4)=25D^{2}X=25*4=100$

Could anyone check if my answers are correct?

**@Edit**

$EX=0$

$D^{2}X$= 4

$EY=E(5x-4)=5EX-4=5*0-4=-4$

$D^{2}Y=D^{2}(5X-4)=25D^{2}X=25*4=100$

Comment: If $X \sim U([-2,2])$, then you should have $E(X) = \frac{1}{2}\left(-2+2\right) = 0$, not $-2$. And what do you mean here by $D^2$? The variance?

Comment: @Prasiortle
Yes D is variance, I edited the main post.

Comment: What makes you think that $\mathbb EX=-\frac12$?

Comment: I read that wrong, my bad

Comment: what makes you think that $\operatorname{var}(X)=4$?

Comment: @kludg in my previous version it was $\frac{(-2-2)^{2}}{12}=\frac{16}{12}$ but some example I found showed $\sigma^{2}=2^{2}=4$ so I followed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation is right, but $Var(X) = \frac {16}{12}= \frac {4}{3} $ and then $Var(Y) = 25*Var(X)= 33.333 $

Comment: Thank you, any idea why would Var(X) = 4? (Did example I follow mistake it for normal distribution instead of uniform distribution?)

Comment: Yes, the notation $\sigma^2$ is typically used for the normal distribution. For the uniform distribution $U([a,b])$, the variance is $\frac{1}{12}\left(b-a\right)^2$.